# Is Modifying the content of a file possible in mqfte using ant task?

Tags: ant, ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I have to substitute the letter "A" with letter "C" in the content of a txt file.

Let test.txt be a txt file. The content is as follows:

Ace Apple

I need the content in the destination folder to be as :

Cce Cpple.

Is this possible in mqfte using ant tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "yes."

The longer answer is that you can do anything with Ant that can be scripted, including calling other scripts.  The approach would be to use a post-destination call that would edit the file after it arrives.  This call won't fire if the file transfer fails.  If the transfer succeeds the post-destination call does fire and will run your task or script to edit the file.  Just remember that if you configure this to run as a monitor, it will fire on every file transfer.  If you want to run it as an ad-hoc transfer you will need to submit it from the command line since the GUI does not support the pre/post calls.

Comment: You can call sed directly if the command is short and doesn't require multiple levels of shell interpolation or substitution.  But if that were the case you'd want to script the command.